# Website to identify what is my screen size as per Bootstrap Naming

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any website which tells what is my window size?

> Like

X-Small / Small / Medium / Large / Extra large / Extra extra large

Based on the window width I adjust in browser.

Comment: How to you think that would work? How big is small exactly? 400px? 800px? ...?

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/)? It's [right there](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#grid-options). I just googled "bootstrap screen size".

Comment: Here, I created one for you: https://jimmys20.github.io/WhatIsMyBootstrapBreakpoint/

Comment: @Dimitris Maragkos, Fantastic.  This is what I wanted.  Please post it as answer so that I mark your solution as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple website that shows your browser's screen size according to the [available Bootstrap breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/breakpoints/#available-breakpoints).

https://jimmys20.github.io/WhatIsMyBootstrapBreakpoint/